# Google Maps, Passing in an Array of Lat and Lng for Markers?

Tags: jquery, arrays, google-maps

I have a call back url, that i'm am pulling out the Lat and Lng to display as markers on a Google Maps.  I am putting them into an array but I think i have to split them up in order for Google Maps to understand them.

```
function jsonData(){
        $.ajax({
            url: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=FUKXDJRWIB0AQ2MQUKUEUSB3KW2TMYKUMFGYLYUHBBH14CQ0&v=20120126,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(results) {
                var lat;
                var long;
                var paths = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < results.response.checkins.items.length; i++) {
                    var lat = results.response.checkins.items[i].venue.location.lat;
                    var long = results.response.checkins.items[i].venue.location.lng;   
                    var pathDetails = lat +"," + long;
                    paths.push(pathDetails);
                }
                drop(paths);
            } 
        });
   };


        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var map;

        var neighborhoods = [];

        var markers = [];
        var iterator = 0;

        function initialize() {
              var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
              directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
              //var newyork = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7051157, -74.0088305);
              var myOptions = {
                zoom:1,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              }

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
              directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

              var start = "new york, ny";
              var end = "los angeles, ca";
              var request = {
                origin:start,
                destination:end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
              };
              directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                }
              });
          }


          function drop(neighborhoods) {
            console.log("Passing in data: " + neighborhoods);
            for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                addMarker();
              }, i * 200);
            }
          }

          function addMarker() {
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              position: neighborhoods[iterator],
              map: map,
              draggable: false,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            }));
            iterator++;
          }   

$(document).ready(function() {
    jsonData();
    drop();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made about 4 changes, what's important is neighborhoods is both a local variable to drop (I renamed it to nx) and the global.

See the changes here:
http://jsfiddle.net/JVQTK/

Answer (score 0):

You could store an array OF arrays, so that each array element would have the lat and lng separate, then you could refer to them like: `arrayName[i][0]` and `arrayName[i][1]`.

I think it also might work if you turn the points into a google LatLng, and then store an array of those.

edit: for how your code is now, I think the second option would be better...otherwise, in your addMarker function, you should take the values, turn them into a LatLng, and then use that as the point